# Detect if the user is leaving the page and delete with ajax

Tags: javascript

I am looking to delete the saved data in the case the user has not completed all the steps in my web page.

This is what I have done:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

function confirmExit()
{
    if (!$('body').find('.wizard_completed').attr('class')) {
        if (confirm($('body').find('.exit_confirm').html())) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {action: delete_event}
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the user clicks on "cancel" the page get refreshed anyway even if it should not be refreshed. How can I avoid refreshing the page if clicked on cancel?

Comment: `$('body').find('.wizard_completed').attr('class')` -> `$('.wizard_completed').length`
`$('body').find('.exit_confirm')` -> `$('.exit_confirm')`

Comment: That's a suggested edit to your code.

Comment: @mishik thanks but what about my question? :)

Comment: Answer section is for answers. Comments section for suggestions and questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the `onunload` event to make the AJAX call and in `onbeforeunload` show the message:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
window.onunload = onunload;

function confirmExit()
{
    if (!$('body').find('.wizard_completed').attr('class')) {
        return $('body').find('.exit_confirm').html();
    }
}

function onunload(){
     $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {action: delete_event}
            });
}
```